# How do Patrol Wards work?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

Occasionally, I'll pick up a Patrol Ward floor trap, which boasts the description:

> Prevents patrols from spawning within the range of the Ward.

Can I use this trap to funnel monsters during the objective defense phase? I've tried placing this trap in a few missions, but haven't noticed any difference. What exactly are the patrols that these traps affect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6qghmz/was_exactly_does_the_patrol_ward_do/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6pa67e/how_does_this_trap_work/), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6ovq1d/can_anyone_explain_what_the_patrol_ward_does/)), it appears that patrols are the purple glowy doors that appear at random and spawn a roaming group of monsters that run to another randomly spawned door.

Since I'd only tried using these traps in Stonewood, I didn't see a real difference, as these patrols were not exceptionally common. However, they occur *much* more frequently in Plankerton, especially while trying to build a fort around an objective. In most cases, the patrols attack unfinished structures and cause a bit of trouble.

This is what these traps are designed to prevent. By placing a Patrol Ward in or around your fort, it prevents these doors from spawning nearby and dropping a pack of monsters next to you. While not exceptionally helpful in Stonewood, they become much more important in Plankerton and beyond (so think twice before scrapbooking your schematics or trashing the ones you find!). However, these traps **do not** affect spawns related to the objective, so you can't use them to funnel monsters when defending.

Comment: Yeah it comes back to the whole more comes later in the game.

Comment: @n_palum I think you accidentally a word or two. ;)

Comment: @MageXy I think he meant "the whole 'more comes later in the game'". Punctuation is key!

Comment: ^ ain't nobody got time for punctuation

Comment: We did a "Ride the Lightning" mission and placed the patrol wards on top of some inconvenient spawn points (the purple tornadoes that show up after you put the blu-glo in) and they seemed to suppress spawns from them for a period of time. We didn't really check on them to see how long they lasted during the defense though, so it could have been coincidence.

Comment: @ColleenV I'm pretty sure that is coincidence. The patrol wards only stop patrols from spawning (the bright purple doors which spawn a couple of husks). They don't have any effect on "main objective" spawns.